# Was bedeutet »Müslifresser« in gegebenem Kontext?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Heute existieren bereits Hunderte solcher komplementärer Währungssysteme, ohne dass sie bisher Eingang in den wirtschaftswissenschaftlichen Mainstream und die Politik gefunden haben. Wir glauben, dass unsere Gesellschaft an einem ähnlichen Wendepunkt steht wie in den 70er- und frühen 80er-Jahren, als die Öko-Bewegung Fahrt aufnahm und mit der   Partei ihr politisches Sprachrohr fand. Zu Beginn wurde das grüne Gedankengut und Wertesystem als von **Müslifressern** **ersponnen** **belächelt** **und** **abgetan**. Heute scheint es uns vollkommen normal, dass sogar konservative Parteien über Windparks in der Nordsee, Schadstoffbelastung in Gemüse und die Effizienz von Solarmodulen diskutieren: Die Öko-Bewegung ist Mainstream geworden.

Was bedeutet der markierte Satz, inbesondere das Wort *Müslifresser*?

Comment: As asked before: we need better titles to your questions. Otherwise they will not help anybody later. Please also take care to restrict your question to **one** topic only. In this case we can only guess what may have been unclear to your.

Comment: I added a more suitable title. As *Mueslifresser* und *ersponnen* seem to be the problematic words, I adressed that in the body, too.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser: actually in this repeated case I was adressing the OP who should have done that. I feel it is not OK that they keep relying on us to put effort in their questions. By doing so they impose work on other people. In any case it is **them** who ask for our help.

Comment: @Takkat I know what you mean, but I don't think the OP cares about his question beeing edited, if he has already got 2 answers. I just edited it for the sake of one beeing able to find the question, as well as to make it more clear.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser: at least restrict it to one topic then.

Comment: Ich habe es so empfunden, als ob *als von Müslifressern ersponnen belächelt* der problematische Ausdruck wäre.

Comment: @DavidVogt: dewegen **muss** der/die OP hier Klarheit schaffen, denn sie haben die Müesliantwort als richtig akzeptiert und *als* ist nicht fett gedruckt... Es hatte schon Gründe, weshalb die Frage in ihrer [Urform](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/48778/revisions) als unklar geschlossen werden musste. Für zukünftige Besucher ist das  Textfragment sowieso uninteressant, *Müslifresser* wird vielleicht noch einmal gesucht.

Comment: @user26646, woher stammt der Text? Quelle bitte ergänzen!

Comment: Es gibt übrigens einige Weibseiten mit Begriffserklärungen zu Müslifresser, z.B. [stupidedia](https://www.stupidedia.org/stupi/M%C3%BCslifresser), [mundmische](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/24687-Mueslifresser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

alles klar ausser **Müslifresser**

Muesli; Swiss German: Müesli, non-Swiss Standard German: Müsli is a breakfast dish based on raw rolled oats and other ingredients like grains, fresh or dried fruits, seeds and nuts, that may be mixed with milk, soy milk, almond milk, other plant milks, yogurt, or fruit juice. Wikipedia

Müsli sind nicht etwa Mäuschen, was der eine oder andere meinen könnte, sondern Müesli  (**Birchermüesli**). Müeslifresser ist ein Schimpfwort und ein Pejorativ für die Grünen (Ökologische Partei in Deutschen Landen, Germany, Austria, Switzerland) als Inbegriff von Vegetarischem und naturnahem Lebensstil. (Ernährung, Konsum)

[Google-Suche nach Birchermüesli](https://www.google.com/search?q=bircherm%C3%BCesli&rlz=1C9BKJA_enCH812CH813&oq=bircherm%C3%BCesli&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.8818j1j8&hl=en-GB&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=_)

Comment: **Müesli** and **ausser** are correct spellings in Swiss German, right?

Answer (score 4):

## Müslifresser

*Müslifresser* ist wie von Albrecht Hügli beschrieben eine abwertende Bezeichnung für "grün" eingestellte Menschen. Obwohl das Wort *Müslifresser* jüngeren Datums zu sein scheint (frühester Treffer bei Google Books von 1982), fühle ich mich dabei immer an die sogenannte [Lebensreform](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebensreform)-Bewegung erinnert.

## Erspinnen

*Ersponnen* ist das Partizip II von *erspinnen*. *Spinnen* bezeichnet die Herstellung von Fäden; *erspinnen* bedeutet in etwa *etwas durch Spinnen hervorbringen*. Es gibt einige Verben mit dem Präfix *er-*, bei denen das Akkusativobjekt als Hervorgebrachtes angesehen werden kann: *einen Vorschlag erarbeiten, eine Tabelle erstellen, Neuland erschließen*. Eine *ersponnene Geschichte* ist ein Kunstprodukt und man unterstellt (wie bei einer *erfundenen Geschichte*), daß sie falsch ist.

## *Als*-Phrase

Die *als*-Phrase ist interessant. Man betrachte:

> Die Katze sah ihn an und miaute.
>   Wir sehen den Vorschlag als guten Kompromiss an.
>   "Wir denken, daß der Vorschlag ein guter Kompromiss ist."

Im ersten Fall ist *ihn* sowohl syntaktisch als auch semantisch Objekt von *ansehen*. Aber im zweiten Fall ist *Vorschlag* nicht semantisches Objekt zu *ansehen*; vielmehr besteht eine Beziehung zwischen *Vorschlag* und *Kompromiss*, als ob sie durch *sein* verbunden wären.

Bei *belächeln* bleibt das Akkusativobjekt zwar semantisches Objekt, aber es kommt eine zum obigen Beispiel parallele Prädikation hinzu:

> Man belächelte seinen Vorschlag.
>   "Man lächelte über seinen Vorschlag."
>   Man belächelte seinen Vorschlag als weltfremd.
>   "Man belächelte seinen Vorschlag und fand, daß er weltfremd sei."

Eine Paraphrase des Ausgangssatzes (unter Streichung von *abgetan*) wäre dann:

> Zu Beginn wurde über das grüne Gedankengut und Wertesystem gelächelt und man fand, daß es von Müslifressern erfunden sei.

Comment: up vote for your example: ersponnene geschichte!

Answer (score 2):

> Zu Beginn wurde das grüne Gedankengut und Wertesystem *als* von Müslifressern ersponnen belächelt und abgetan.

Das ist ein Vergleich um das *als* herum.

> Zu Beginn wurde es belächelt und abgetan.
>
> Zu Beginn wurde das grüne Gedankengut und Wertesystem belächelt und abgetan.
>
> Zu Beginn wurde es als von Müslifressern ersponnen belächelt und abgetan.

Alles klar damit? Dann bleibt nur noch das Wort *Müslifresser*. Jemand, der Müsli frisst. Und vielleicht noch das Wort *ersponnen*, was eine humorvolle Neubildung aus *ersinnen* (to conceive) und *spinnen* (to be bonkers) ist.

Comment: nein, Müslifreser hat hier ein Euphemismus  oder eine Metonymie, der Autor meint nicht das Wort buchstäblich

Comment: Das *ersponnen* scheint mir hier näher an der ursprünglichen Bedeutung von *spinnen* zu sein.

Comment: Vote up für erspinnen spinnen ersinnen.

Comment: user26646: Doch, der Autor meint das schon wörtlich. *Fressen* tun nur Tiere oder unersättliche Menschen, und ein Müslifresser ist demnach nicht etwa ein Schweizer (der *isst* sein Müesli selbstverständlich), sondern jemand, der "virtue signalling" betreibt, indem er in seinem "Gesundheitsbewusstsein" unersättlich ist. Was natürlich weder gesund noch gottgefällig ist.

Comment: Man kann vor so ziemlich jedes Verb ein er- setzen, wenn dadurch etwas erlangt wird. In Schillers Räubern findet sich *erwimmern* (etwas durch Wimmern erlangen).

Comment: "erspinnen" [2] übertragen: sich etwas ausdenken (herumspinnen) ist doch keine Wortneuschöpfung, oder? https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erspinnen